# Get a DataSet returned from SOAP as XML?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, dataset, asmx

We have a .NET 2 SOAP web service meant for consumption by another app that is internal to our organisation. The web service returns a .NET dataset like so:

```
public System.Data.DataSet GetStatementFor(string contractList,
  System.DateTime startDate, System.DateTime endDate)
```

Now in one of the use cases it is necessary to get to the DataSet object's XML. Now obviously the DataSet is being returned via XML in any case, so I was wondering if it is possible to just use the XML that represents it in SOAP. Normally the XML is wrapped into a DataSet object which I will then need to serialize once again. Can I skip these last two steps and still return a DataSet for the cases where it makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the WebService transfers a DataSet in SOAP formatting, which is different form the format DataSet.WriteXml() uses.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But is it possible to get my hands on that SOAP formatting? It still encodes the dataset's meta and data, so it should do for their purposes. As I understand, they essentially plan to push it through a XSL transform to get into the format they want.

Comment: Prying it from the WebService communication would be messy. But you can run it through a SOAP formatter after reception. I would double check what 'they' want first though.

Comment: I think the plan is to feed it into existing code that takes a string of XML. Perhaps I should just tell them to do as you say - DataSet.WriteXML() will work, but I thought it could be possible to skip the conversions from and to XML.

Comment: No, the XML you're looking for does not exist. You're thinking there's a string or XmlDocument sitting around somewhere. Not so. What if the message was large?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused what you want. DataSet will be serialized to XML and deserialized on the other end back into a DataSet why do you need to care about the underlaying XML?

Comment: Indeed. I don't understand it either, but that was the request I got.